# Subset panel dataset for different periods for each country

Tags: r, subset, panel-data

I have a panel dataset with values for 15 variables for 120 countries over the period 1789-2020. The unit of analysis is country-year. Here's a simplified version of the dataset just to show what it looks like.

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 20
Data <- data.frame(Country=rep(LETTERS[1:5], n/5),date=sample(1789:2020, n, replace=TRUE), variable1=sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE), variable2=sample(10:100, n, replace=TRUE),variable3=rnorm(n))
Data
```

I want to subset the data such that I get a subsetted data where I only have all the data for each country after whichever year they each transitioned to democracy - e.g. Country A (1965-2020), Country B (1988-2020), Country C (1998-2020), and so, for all of the countries, the period range should be set differently for each country.

Is there a way to do this other than just subsetting the data manually like the following code below, which is what I've done so far? I would just run these codes below if the number of countries was small, but it isn't in the actual dataset that I'm working on, so it would be great if there is some other way. Thank you!

```
Data2 <- subset(Data, {country_name == "A" & year >= "2000"} |                          {country_name == "B" & year >= "1991"} | 
{country_name == "C" & year >= "1997"} | 
{country_name == "D" & year >= "1994"} | 
{country_name == "E" & year >= "1997"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a lookup dataframe which has the country name and the year they transitioned to democracy. Join the two dataframes and keep only the rows that has `date` value greater than the `year`.

```
lookup <- data.frame(Country = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 
                     year = c(2000, 1995, 1997, 1994, 1997))

result <- merge(Data, lookup, by = 'Country') |> subset(date > year)
```

Or using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)  
result  <- inner_join(Data, lookup, by = 'Country') %>% filter(date > year)
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the function to subset the data such that for country A, I subset for 1914~2004, 2005~2018, 2019~2021; but the specific periods differ by country? Country B for example 1930~1963, 1964-1965, 1966-1983; Country C would be 1900-1991, 1992-2018, 2019-2021, etc?

Comment: @LLJ Sure, but for consistency please ask it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you - I've just posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284423/how-to-subset-panel-data-for-different-periods-for-each-country

Answer (score 0):

We may do a non-equi join with key/val dataset

```
library(data.table)
keydat <- data.frame(Country = c("A", "C", 'D', "E"),
      date = c(2000, 1997, 1994, 1997))
setDT(Data)[keydat, on = .(Country, date >= date)]
```